# Get end of string that matches pattern with lodash

Tags: javascript, regex, lodash

How can I get the last integer(s) at the end of the string including the dash before it using lodash?

```
'hello-world-bye-945'
```

So the end result is just `-945`.

Comment: Does it have to be with `lodash`? Pure regex or vanilla js would do though..

Comment: `'-' + 'hello-world-bye-945'.split('-').pop()`

Comment: @choz nope, vanilla js is acceptable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method

```js
console.log(
  'hello-world-bye-945'.match(/-\d+$/)[0]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[_.words](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#words)**.

**E.g**

```
var str1 = 'hello-world-bye-945';
var str2 = 'hello-world-bye';
var pattern = /-(\d+)$/;

_.words(str1, pattern)[0]
// Returns "-945"

_.words(str2, pattern)[0]
// Returns "undefined"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`, `String.prototype.slice()`

```js
var str = "hello-world-bye-945";
var match = str.slice(str.lastIndexOf("-"));
console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
s = 'hello-world-bye-945'.split('-');
ans="-"+s[s.length-1]
console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
-[0-9A-z$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!]+$
```

[0-9A-z$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!] match any character in the list

"+" match unlimited time

$ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

Comment: _last integer(s)_. Author don't need to use that weird pattern.